# Passing color to fragment shader from Javascript

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am currently learning webgl and have a question.
I am trying to make a triangle and passing the color info into fragment shader from js file. The following is my js code:

```js
var VSHADER_SOURCE = 
    'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n'+
    'attribute vec4 a_Color;\n'+
    'varying vec4 v_Color;\n'+
    'void main(){\n'+
        'gl_Position = a_Position;\n'+
        'v_Color = a_Color;\n'+
    '}\n';


var FSHADER_SOURCE = 
    'precision highp float;\n'+
    'varying vec4 v_Color;\n'+
    'void main() {\n'+
        'gl_FragColor = v_Color;\n'+
    '}\n';

function main(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
    var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
    if(!gl){
        console.log('Error!');
        return;
    }
    //Init shaders.
    if(!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)){
        console.log('Error!');
        return;
    }
    var vertices = new Float32Array([-0.8, -0.8, 0.8, -0.8, 0.0, 0.8]);
    var color = new Float32Array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]);
    var buffer_object = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_object);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

    var color_object = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_object);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, color, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    var a_Color = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Color');
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Color);

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);


    return 0;
}
```

This have to create a blue triangle but the only thing I see is a canvas filled with black color. Can anyone tell me what's missing?? I created two buffer objects and used one for vertex and the other for color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a lot of issues with your example but... specific problems.

You're only supplying colors for the first vertex.

You have 3 vertices but only 1 color. You should be getting an error for that. 
**Did you check the JavaScript Console for errors?**

You have 3 options to fix that

1. Provide a color for each vertex

   ```
   new Float32Array([
     0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
   ]);
   ```
2. Turn off the a_Color attribute and supply a constant value

   ```
   gl.disableVertexAtttibArray(a_Color);
   gl.vertexAttrib4f(a_Color, 0, 0, 1, 1);
   ```
3. Use a uniform instead of an attribute + varying

   remove all references of `a_Color` and `v_color` and instead have your
   fragment shader be

   ```
   precision highp float;
   uniform vec4 u_Color;
   void main() {
     gl_FragColor = u_Color;
   }
   ```

   Now you'd set the color with

   At Init time

   ```
   // Lookup the location
   var u_colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_Color");
   ```

   At render time

   ```
   // Set the uniform
   gl.uniform4f(u_colorLocation, 0, 0, 1, 1);
   ```

If you choose #2 you'll likely run into another issue that you'll get a warning that  attirbute 0 is not enabled because, at least on my computer, `a_Color` is assigned to attribute 0. Turning it off means it has to be emulated which is slow. The solution is to make sure `a_Position` is in attribute 0 by calling `gl.bindAttribLocation` **before** linking the program.

Other issues:

Your `initShader` function is apparently creating a program and attaching it to the WebGLRenderContext (`gl.program`). Most WebGL projects have many shader programs so it would probably be best to just return the program. In other words, instead of

```
initShader(...);
gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, ...)
```

You probably want

```
var program = initShader(...);
gl.getAttribLocation(program, ...)
```

You'll need to fix initShader so it returns the program that was created rather than hacking it on to the WebGLRenderingContext.

Also you're using `precision highp float`. That won't work on many phones. Unless you're sure you need `highp` it's better to use `mediump`.